# Can you make a Google Cloud Tasks Queue retry FASTER than 6 per minute?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to experiment with the Cloud Tasks retry behavior using an HTTP Cloud Function that fails with a preset probability (code below). I make 100 of these tasks that fail with 99% chance and I can't get my queue to retry faster than 6 tasks per minute, and I don't know why. I tried changing all the limits I could think of and eventually just maxed everything out to no avail.

```
def fail_randomly():
    global fail_chance
    random_number = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if random_number <= fail_chance:
        raise Exception("Failed with random number " + str(random_number))
    return "Success"

+----------------+-------+
|  Rate limits   |       |
+----------------+-------+
| Max rate       | 500/s |
| Max concurrent | 5000  |
| Max burst size | 100   |
+----------------+-------+

+--------------------+-----------+
|  Retry parameters  |           |
+--------------------+-----------+
| Max attempts       | 1000      |
| Min interval       | 0.001s    |
| Max interval       | 0.010s    |
| Max doublings      | 1         |
| Max retry duration | Unlimited |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I guess there is an exponential backoff, to preserve the service. Reduce the % of errors should increase the retry speed

Comment: When you retry to add the task, you use the same id or those are generated by the API?

Comment: @YeriPelona Retrying is an automatic behavior of a Cloud Tasks Queue. Whenever my task (which is a Cloud Function) throws an exception, the job fails and will be retried. The retry behavior is configured in the queue. That's pretty much all I know.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere That's correct, reducing the error rate to like 12% lets me get more failed tasks per second. Yes there is an exponential backoff, but it's supposed to be configurable. From what I've read in the docs, I'm not getting the expected behavior:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/tasks/queues/create